# How to hide/Remove the title field from default view of List in sharepont 2013 online

Tags: sharepoint-online

Iam trying to hide/remove the title field from my list view programmatically but its still displaying .tried alot but without luck. Code is as follows.

```
        List list = ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
        View defaultView = list.DefaultView;
            if(defaultView.ViewFields.Contains(fieldName)){

              defaultView.ViewFields.Remove(fieldName);
              defaultView.Update();

             ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to removed `LinkTitle` field from default view of List. Here is my answer.

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://siteUrl"))
 {
   List list = ctx.Site.RootWeb.Lists.GetByTitle("myListName");
   View defaultView = list.DefaultView;
   ViewFieldCollection viewFieldCollection = defaultView.ViewFields;
   ctx.Load(viewFieldCollection);
   ctx.ExecuteQuery();

   if (defaultView.ViewFields.Contains("LinkTitle"))
    {
       defaultView.ViewFields.Remove("LinkTitle");
       defaultView.Update();
       ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider loading the field first then set hidden property true.

```
 using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://siteUrl"))
 {
    Field field = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("myListName").Fields.GetByTitle("Title");
    ctx.Load(field);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
    field.Hidden = true;
    field.Update();
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
 }
```

Comment: thank u i will test and reply back